# I can't merge a branch because I get a msg saying that I have uncommitted changes in xcuserdata that I cannot commit

Tags: git, merge, gitignore

When I try to commit it just shows 2 files (which as @Jeff points out) seem to be duplicates of xcuserdata.

[image]

I have a .gitignore see below :

## Xcode

```
.DS_Store
*/build/
*.pbxuser
!default.pbxuser
*.mode1v3
!default.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
!default.mode2v3
*.perspectivev3
!default.perspectivev3
xcuserdata/*
profile
*.moved-aside
DerivedData
.idea/
*.hmap
```

My gitignore was called default.gitignore then I changed it to .gitignore, neither changed the outcome.

So :
- is my .gitignore being ignored for some reason
- why do I have 2 xcuserdata files and how do I get rid of one
- looks the second file is a breakpoint compare failing - how do I stop this
- and I can't even merge these files (Save button greyed out) to get around the problem and thus can't commit and thus can't merge.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to see the full error in the screenshot, but what is happening is that you are trying to do a merge while you have local changes, which you do **not** want to do. Instead, commit your changes first, *then* do the merge.

Comment: Hi David, yes I have tried that but I can't get beyond the commit.  I have changed the screen shot in the original question to show what the commit does.  It committed the real source code changes but leaves some files uncommitted, and which it won't allow me to commit.  The Save button is greyed out in the image above.

So I have 2 files that don't match and that I can't merge and thus can't commit and thus can't merge the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to merge in the two files mentioned in the error message but instead want to exclude those files:

If you want to ignore everything in the `xcuserdata` directory you should use `xcuserdata/*` relative to the .gitignore file. I'm not sure how your project is setup, but it looks like you have two of those folders:

- Twoater.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata
- Twoater.xcodeproj/xcuserdata

Comment: I think you are on the right track.  I do not know how I ended up with 2 of these but the question is what do I do to resolve the problem.

I now have uncommitted source code which is preventing me from merging my branch.  See screen image.

Comment: I deleted Twoater.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate then I went back to the commit screen in xCode and it reappeared as before.  I went back into Terminal and found that the file had been re-created

Comment: xCode could be creating that file, I don't really know. If it's a system file and it's not part of your codebase and not anything you need to share with anyone, I'd say you can ignore it. Are you saying that when you type ``git status`` the file still shows up as ``modified`` or ``untracked`` even after adding the path to .gitignore?